# Windows 8 & Server 2012: SQL Server Connection Delay

Tags: networking, windows-8, sql-server, sql, windows-server-2012

When connecting from a Windows Server 2012 or Windows 8 box to a SQL Server machine, it takes 2 sec to open a SQL connection and .5 sec for any SQL command to execute. Connecting to the same SQL Server machine from any other windows machine does not have this problem. Also, the network, outside of SQL Server connections, are working fine. This delay occurs irrelevant of the SQL Server version (2005, 2008, or 2012).

My best guess was IPv6 getting in the way, but turning that off (& rebooting) provides no relief. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A co-worker was able to identify that Trend Micro was the culprit. We have removed it from our Windows 8 & Server 2012 instances as a result and are looking for alternatives...